# Crypto module not loading randomUUID() when viewing a local network IP address

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cryptojs

I feel like I'm missing something basic here, I've got a React app that I'm trying to use the crypto module in the browser. Specifically I'm trying to use the `randomUUID()` function, which should be present in [Chrome versions > 92](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID). This all works great when I'm viewing my app on localhost, I can import crypto and see the `randomUUID()` function in the console.

But weirdly when I try to view the same app on my local network IP address (192.168.X.XX), I can't see `randomUUID` anymore in the console. My app is also failing to get the function. I can see crypto is still importing, but I can't see `randomUUID` in there, the console only shows  the `getRandomValues()` function. I also double checked that in both instances I'm running Chrome 108 via `navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]`

I also tested this on Safari and can see the behavior replicated there: I can see `crypto.randomUUID()` on localhost, but not on my local network IP address. Anyone know why this is could be happening?

Localhost:
[image]

192.168.X.XX:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is because a secure context is required ー which normally means https/TLS, but the hostname `localhost` is special-cased to be considered a secure context, even over normal http (non-https, non-TLS). But any 192.168.X.XX host is not special-cased in that way, and can otherwise never be a secure context, because it can't have an SSL certificate. So you either use `localhost` or else use a hostname for which you have an SSL certificate.

Comment: Ohh that would make a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID):

**Secure context**: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.